# What constitutes "improper use" of the javascript Eval feature?

Tags: javascript

Eval is a notoriously controversial language feature.  Douglas Crockford flat out rejects it. I'm wondering what specific risks Eval brings about.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) question, `Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks`.

What are some improper uses of the Eval command, and what security holes do they open up?

Answer (score 32):

Back when I was implementing the JScript engine I advocated having **EVAL IS EVIL** shirts printed up but sadly we never got around to it.

My biggest problem with eval is not the obvious malicious code injection attack, though that is certainly of enormous concern. My biggest problem with it is that people tend to use it as a Really Big Hammer to solve really small problems. Most of the real-world usages I saw of "eval" in the wild when I was on the JScript team could have been trivially solved by using a lookup table; and since every object in JScript *already is a lookup table* it's not like that was an onerous burden.  Eval *starts the compiler again* and *completely destroys the ability of the compiler to optimize your code*.

For some more thoughts in this vein see my articles from 2003 on the subject:

[General evilness](https://ericlippert.com/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/)

[Injection attack evilness](https://ericlippert.com/2003/11/04/eval-is-evil-part-two/)

Comment: What are your thoughts on `eval`ing large chunks of code the way that applications like JSPacker like to? JSPacker + gzip usually results in smaller file sizes than either solution on its own, but as you rightly point out it is essentially firing up a compiler twice on the same piece of code, plus some overhead to do string replacements.

Comment: @Matthew: There is often a tradeoff between space and time, and taking advantage of that tradeoff can sometimes be a big win. If the purpose of the technique is to improve performance then my opinion is that if careful measurement shows that it is a significant win in realistic scenarios without introducing security holes, great, do that. But I don't know enough about the specific technique to criticize its details.

Comment: I wish one of the answers I had seen *either* here *or* on SO itself would have stated what your second link states: that `eval()` is *not* a security risk on client (browser) code.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the security holes are the same sort of holes as with SQL injection, namely concatenating user input into JavaScript code. The difference being that while there are ways to ensure this doesn't happen with SQL, there's not much you can do with JavaScript.

As a trivial and useless example, a simplistic JavaScript calculator:

```
textbox1.value = eval(textbox2.value);
```

One correct usage examples are some of the JavaScript packers that compress JavaScript by pulling out common words and replacing them with short 1-2 character replacements. The packer then outputs all this along with string replacement code based on the dictionary generated then evals the result.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that are impossible to do in JS without an eval-like function (`eval`, `Function`, and maybe more).

Take `apply` for example. It is easy to use when using it on ordinary function calls:

`foo.apply(null, [a, b, c])`

But how would you do this for objects you are creating via new syntax?

`new Foo.apply(null, [a, b, c])` doesn't work, nor do similar forms.

But you can work around this limitation via `eval` or `Function` (I use `Function` in this example):

```
Function.prototype.New = (function () {
    var fs = [];
    return function () {
        var f = fs[arguments.length];
        if (f) {
            return f.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        var argStrs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            argStrs.push("a[" + i + "]");
        }
        f = new Function("var a=arguments;return new this(" + argStrs.join() + ");");
        if (arguments.length < 100) {
            fs[arguments.length] = f;
        }
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}) ();
```

Example:

`Foo.New.apply(null, [a, b, c])`;

Of course, you could manually build the functions that `Function.prototype.New` uses, but not only is this verbose and clunky, it (by definition) has to be finite. `Function` allows the code to work for any number of arguments.

Comment: True, but the OP's question was "_What are some improper uses of the Eval command, and what security holes do they open up?_", not "_What is a good use of `eval()`?_"

Comment: @RossPatterson: Guess I mostly looked at the question's title haha.

Comment: Still, +1 for finding a good use for a bad language feature :-)

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat direct answer on my part was developing a developer-oriented API-testing area. We gave a text area on a page, and a Run button. The central point of the page was for them to be able to try things out in Javascript against our iframe-communicating API that weren't so easy to do in a local environment.

Anything malicious that could have been done in that case could also have been done by the developer opening up their F12 tools.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that it should very rarely be used, but I've found a powerful use case for `eval`.

There is an experimental new feature in Firefox called asm.js I've been working with.  It allows for a limited subset of the Javascript language to be compiled into native code.  Yes, this is very awesome, but it does have limitations.  You can think of the limited subset of Javascript as being a C-like language embedded in Javascript.  It isn't really meant to be read or written by humans.

This limited subset of Javascript does not allow me to inject my runtime-generated code into the compiled code once it's been compiled.

I have written some code that allows a user to write, in familiar notation, a mathematical expression, and have it converted on the fly to asm.js code.  Unless I wanted to have the code processed on the server side (which I don't), `eval` is the only tool that allows me to have the resulting code processed by the browser in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the most important thing when working with `eval` is to keep it safe. For that, you want to do thorough argument checking, and keep `eval` 'ed code simple since it is generally a lot harder to maintain and secure run-time generated code.

That being said, I enjoy using `eval` for two kinds of things (even though there might probably be better, less evil-ish alternatives):

1. Since `eval` is a way of "explicitly caching code", it can be used to improve performance. Note that optimizers are always being improved, but there is simply no guarantee as to what they can do for you. By making things explicit in code, you actually can help the optimizer make smarter decisions.
2. It can also be used to deliver basic forms of type-safety, as well as other language features that JS is lacking, without deteriorating performance.

[This pre-compiled object iterator approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573593/whats-the-fastest-way-to-iterate-over-an-objects-properties-in-javascript/25700742#25700742), for example, shows clear performance benefits when using `eval` for object property iteration. It also shows the beginnings of a powerful type system that can provide implicit constraint checking and a lot more, at little to no cost.

Many seasoned Javascript developers would probably point out that this is a rabbit hole, since, if you start writing Javascript this way, you essentially change the way you use the language. That however might not necessarily be a bad thing for those who enjoy Javascript but are also missing fundamental language features that can only be achieved by changing the way we use the language itself.

Answer (score -3):

I have a situation where eval looks like the way to go, evaluating a string and returning an existing variable whose name is the same as the string.

I have several tables: table1ResultsTable, table2ResultsTable, tableNResultsTable.  I have variables set up with the same names, that are jQuery datatable objects.  I use these to set up the tables and call jQuery datatable functions on them.

Each table has class="resultsTable" assigned.  Now, I need to get the variable when the table is clicked.  I'm doing this:

```
$('resultsTable).on('click', 'td', function(event) {
    var cResultsTable = eval(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id);
    [etc]
});
```

So I'm getting the id of the table in which the cell was clicked, which has the same name as the datatable object variable corresponding to it. If someone has a suggestion for an improvement I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Why do you need eval? The id should be a plain string, not code.  Anyhow, `event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` is horrific.  Further, I'd expect the eval call to generate a "reference error: [id] is not defined" error, unless you're deliberately using evaluable ids (which is broken, wrong, and might cause weird things to happen if you end up generating duplicate ids).

Comment: Perhaps I'm not making myself clear.  The id IS a plain string.  It's the id of the table that has been clicked.  I also have an object variable (set with jQuery datatable() method, referencing the same table) with the same name as the id.  I'm trying to get that variable, to access its functions (in fact, to add the "row_selected" class to the selected row), when the table is clicked.  Since I wrote this, I've come up with an improvement, however.  I just put all the object references in an array, name the elements the same as the id, and plug the id string into that to get the object ref.

Comment: Brian, if you have a better means of finding the id of the table that has been clicked, I'm all ears.  For the datatables function, I need to handle the click event against the cell, and add the row_selected class to its parentNode.  Why I can't just handle the row event and add the class directly to it I don't know, but the row doesn't show as selected when I do that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not making myself clear.  If you call eval on a plain (i.e., non-JS) string, you'll throw an exception.  So, your use of eval doesn't make sense.  If you happen to be generating an object variable with the same name as the id, your code will work...but strikes me as broken.  I'd rather create the variable by using `document.getElementById(ID).MySpecialProperty = MYSPECIALPROPERTYVALUE` (not to say that's great either, but it's better than eval).  As Eric Lippert points out, "every object in JScript already is a lookup table."

Comment: Ok, so you're saying to add a property to the element reference and set it to the datatable object reference?  That sounds tighter to me as well.