# Is a function plotter a legitimate use of eval() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

From PHP development I know that [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951868/562769) and I've recently read [What constitutes “Proper use” of the javascript Eval feature?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/60599/25699) and [Don't be eval](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/). The only proper use of eval I've read is Ajax.

I'm currently developing a visualization tool that lets users see how polynomials can interpolate functions:

- [Example](http://martin-thoma.com/html5/polynom-interpolation.htm?function=Math.sin%28x%29&evaluationSteps=0.05&X_MIN=-15&X_MAX=15&Y_MAX=15&Y_MIN=-15&X_TICKS_STEPS=1&Y_TICKS_STEPS=1&X_FROM=-10&X_TO=10&N_EVALUATION_POINTS=10&points=%5B%5D&tschebyscheffSwitch=true&equallySwitch=true)
- [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/polynom-interpolation)

[image]

I use eval for evaluation of arbitrary functions. Is this a legitimate use of eval? How could I get rid of eval?

I want the user to be able to execute any function of the following forms:

1. a x^i with a,i in R
2. sin, cos, tan
3. b^x with b in R
4. any combination that you can get by

   - adding (e.g. x^2 + x^3 + sin(x)),
   - multiplying (e.g. sin(x)*x^2) or
   - inserting (e.g. sin(x^2))

Comment: You might use a math library on it, for example: http://mathjs.org which takes care of parsing.

Comment: "Eval is evil" is just the same degree of ignorance as the classic stupid rant "goto is evil". Eval is a legitimate and powerful tool for runtime metaprogramming.

Comment: @SK-logic but you need to tread lightly, and there's normally a better way.

Comment: @JanDvorak, metaprogramming is nearly always a better way than anything else. With languages like JavaScript there is no distinction between compile-time and runtime metaprogramming, therefore `eval` is a legitimate way of doing nearly everything (in absence of proper macros).

Comment: @SK-logic Metaprogramming is good if it's what you want. And when you want metaprogramming, there's more tools for metaprogramming than `eval`. `eval` is without a doubt the most powerful, but it's also more brittle and dangerous than more specialized tools. For example, there is no reason to use `eval` for getting an attribute dynamically, as in `eval('obj.'+attrname)` - that's what `obj[attrname]` is for.

Comment: @delnan, `eval` is the most low-level tool, it should be at the very end of your compilation toolchain (just as well as macros in languages like Lisp). This way it's pretty safe yet powerful.

Comment: @LucFranken: Thank you very much for your comment. I've asked this question, but I didn't intend to fix possible issues as this is only a freetime project for me, nothing serious. I just wanted to theoretically know how I should approach something like this. But mathjs is so easy to use, I simply had to change `eval()` to `math.eval()`!

Comment: @moose nice to hear that, yeah it looks quite easy to use. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see nothing not "legitimate", `eval` isn't evil per se and it has been precisely designed to evaluate arbitrary code. It lets you here make a fast, complete expression evaluator without resorting to complex libraries and it gives your user the power of JavaScript.

But right now you're evaluating the input for each `x`. This is very slow.

I would do this so that it can be used more efficiently :

```
var f = Function('x','return '+input);
```

When input is `Math.sin(x)`, this builds a function you can simply call as

```
var x = 3;
var y = f(x);
```

Proof : [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/eval-or-func)

---

If what you want is to let the user enter function with a more classical mathematical language (like `x^y`), then you'd better start importing a mathematical expression parser.

An example of such a library : [Silent Mat's evaluator](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/)

Comment: What about the `^` for exponentiation, as delnan pointed out?

Comment: @JanDvorak There are functions in JavaScript just for that, like `Math.pow`. The point here is not to have to interpret the symbolic expression.

Comment: Well, `eval` definitely *is* evil. evil, _n._: something you should avoid most of the time, but _not_ something you should avoid _all_ the time [(C++ FAQ 6.15)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html). This time seems not to be most of it.

Comment: @JanHudec It's JavaScript, not C++. Most *"eval is evil"* stances are just FUD.

Comment: @dystroy: The definition does not say anything about C++. It only comes from C++ FAQ, where it was needed probably because C++ has many evil constructs. But it applies equally well to all evil constructs from any language.

Comment: C++ does not have many evil constructs.  It was designed by an expert to ease the work of other experts.  It has many constructs that have been widely misused by inexpert programmers.

Comment: @dystroy: I think a problem of my use of eval is that I allow the user to export all settings with one click on "open in window". That also allows users to share graphs, but an attacker could insert any code in `f`. The worst thing I could imagine is somebody creating a script that loads porn / illegal stuff on the site. An innocent user who got that link might think that I put this stuff on my site. But even this issue should now be fixed with mathjs.

Comment: eval doesn't break anything securitywise : any attacker could do the same more comfortably from the console.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to evaluate *Javascript* functions. You want to evaluate some subset of the computable functions from the reals to the reals. So `eval` doesn't do what you want, although in principle you may be able to abuse it for that.
Apart from this philosophical objection, if you want to use `^` for exponentiation, you **can't** use `eval` because it uses Javascript syntax where `^` is binary xor.

If you just want to be done quickly and leave this project, you can use `eval` (especially since this apparently runs on the client site, so the potential for abuse is limited). But the right thing(tm) to do would be using an expression parser specifically for the kind of syntax you want to allow, coupled with an evaluation routine for the parsing output.

It's not that hard to write such a thing yourself, and quite fun. I'd use either the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) or a top down operator precedence parser. Alternatively, use an existing library as recommended in the comments.

Comment: I don't want to use `^` for exponentiation. It's up to the user to use the correct syntax as I've noted in the application. I just used this here to make it easier to read.

Comment: Eval is supposed to be efficient, whereas your ad hoc interpreter is never going to reach the underlying javascript performance. Therefore, the best approach is to compile your simple DSL into JavaScript and then `eval` the resulting code.

Comment: @SK-logic If the evaluation of the function is the bottleneck, yes. Otherwise it's probably not worth the extra twenty lines. While we're talking about performance, note the point of another answer that repeated `eval` would needlessly parse the JS code again and again.

Comment: @delnan, and for plotting it is a bottleneck indeed (since it's an inner loop body). And even if performance is not an issue, there is not much point in reinventing an execution engine if one is already available.

Comment: @SK-logic I've never created a plotter, so I refrain from guessing. And in my experience, just evaluating simple math is simpler than robustly mapping it to another language. For such simple operations, evaluation is trivial.

Comment: @delnan, no, such a compilation is always easier then evaluation. In an evaluator you have to maintain context (variables, etc.), while compilation is a dumb, totally trivial term rewriting, where context is handled by the target language.

Comment: I think the easiest way to parse an expression like that is probably recursive descent, all the definitions are very simple for this sort of math.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum With plain recursive descent, you have to either restructure the grammar to avoid left recursion (something I never quite got the hang of, I admit it), or drop operator precedence. The algorithms I mentioned are as simple as recursive descent, and have handling for operator precedence built in.

Comment: @SK-logic In this language, there is no context to speak of that must be maintained. There's one variable which can be passed along very naturally, and the call stack handles nesting. Compare the addition case: `myEval(node.lhs, x) + myEval(node.rhs, x)` versus `"(" + myComp(node.lhs) + ")+(" + myComp(node.rhs) + ")".` If you want to phrase it as term rewriting, you first need a term rewriting engine and it's still slightly more complex (I suppose the same engine could be used for evaluating it directly).

Comment: @delnan, of course it's a way much easier with such an engine, I would not go into implementing either an evaluator or a code generator without a generic AST-handling library.

Comment: @SK-logic So you suggest that instead of 100 simple lines, we depend on a 100 to 500 line library to bring down our code to 80 simple lines? Ignoring that, you didn't address my concern at all. Would term rewriting simplify the compilation but not the evaluation? And does such a library already exist or would you have to create one yourself? But this is turning into a discussion...

Comment: @delnan, look at this example on difference between compilation and interpretation: http://bit.ly/I2LFdr - it's using a language with built-in term rewriting functionality, so there's no boilerplate, just the essence. If I ever had to do anything with Javascript, I'd write such a library once and won't get back to it ever again.

Comment: @SK-logic You already pointed me to that document once. To put it mildly, it hardly helps you case. **As I already asked**: How does term rewriting help in *this* case? JavaScript as implementation language and compilation target are set in stone, and the input language is just PEMDAS. So your neat esoteric tools are of no use here. How does the term rewriting approach help the compilation of simple arithmetic expressions to JavaScript *more* than it helps the interpretation of the same expressions, such that the former is clearly easier than the latter? Please think and read before replying.

Comment: @delnan, JavaScript is a machine code of a sort. Implementation language could be anything, like CoffeeScript (which features proper typing, afair). This esoteric tool is so dumb and simple that it can be implemented in any language (I did it with C and Forth), and I cannot imagine programming in any language without such tool (likely my past experience with Mathematica bent my mind too much into thinking in term rewriting), so, as it is essential anyway, it's safe to assume such a tool is already in place. And in presence of such tool, compilation is always easier than interpretation.

Comment: @SK-logic You **still** did not address 90% of what I said, you just pick and choose minor points and repeat claims I've challenged several times, up to and including code examples. You can stop commenting now.

Comment: @delnan, you're saying that this adds complexity. My point is that such a library is a must-have anyway, so it should not be accounted for the total number of lines of code. I cannot understand your obsession with interpreters, there is no point in interpretation at all when you can compile and run (i.e., use `eval`). And it is worrying that you count string concatenation as "too complex".

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people who know `eval` is dangerous on the server side also reflexively shun it on the client side.  There is a huge difference.  It is not a security hole to be able to execute your own arbitrary code on your own computer.  The only time to be concerned about `eval` security on the client side is if you're using it to execute code from an untrusted third party, for example from email or a twitter feed.

However, there are other factors to consider.  The `eval` solution is going to be much simpler for basic functionality, but much more difficult to add things like useful error messages.  You may end up implementing your own parser anyway to add those sorts of features.

There are also performance considerations, but I think the difference is likely to be negligible.  `eval` will probably have higher startup times, but faster execution times.

Personally, I would use `eval` for a tool for my own use or within my company, for its simplicity of development.  For wider distribution, I would want the polish a custom parser can provide.